# How to restore hardware functions on lubuntu after botched xrdp install?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, vnc, interface, xrdp

I attempted to install xrdp onto my lubuntu laptop, and now when I boot into my lubuntu 18.04 desktop, I cannot interact in any way. However, this is only with the hardware on the actual laptop, in the desktop. I can use the desktop through a vnc session on my phone, and can use recovery mode etc. on the actual laptop. 100% not a hardware issue.

How can I undo whatever occured when I installed xrdp? I’ve already uninstalled and reinstalled xrdp multiple times along with disabling the service in systemctl.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354154/installing-xrdp-on-lubuntu-18-04-broke-xorg-on-console-how-to-troubleshoot