# Installing xRDP on Lubuntu 18.04 broke Xorg on console - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, xorg, remote-desktop, xrdp

On an out-of-the-box (plus apt update; apt upgrade) **Lubuntu** 18.04 box, I followed [these steps](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/linux/lubuntu-setup-remote-desktop-with-xrdp/) to install xrdp:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
echo 'lxsession -e LXDE -s Lubuntu' > ~/.xsession
sudo service xrdp restart
```

This worked right away, but it broke Xorg on the console. From another host with Remmina I can still use the system with a complete, 100% functional GUI, but the console remains stuck in text mode (black screen with cursor).

I believe this is a similar scenario to the one outlined in [this unanswered 2 year old post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135544/how-to-restore-hardware-functions-on-lubuntu-after-botched-xrdp-install).

In /var/log/Xorg.0.log I find:

```
[    29.206] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[    29.232] (II) glamor: EGL version 1.4:
[    29.255] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[    29.264] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 has no monitor section
[    29.271] (II) modeset(0): Output DVI-D-1 has no monitor section
[    29.362] (II) modeset(0): Output SVIDEO-1 has no monitor section
[    29.381] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[    29.381] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA-1
[    29.381] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    29.381] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    29.381] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[    29.381] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "848x480"x60.0   33.75  848 864 976 1088  480 486 494 517 +hsync +vsync (31.0 kHz e)
[    29.381] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    29.386] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DVI-D-1
[    29.477] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output SVIDEO-1
[    29.477] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 connected
[    29.478] (II) modeset(0): Output DVI-D-1 disconnected
[    29.478] (II) modeset(0): Output SVIDEO-1 disconnected
[    29.478] (II) modeset(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[    29.478] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 using initial mode 1024x768 +0+0
[    29.478] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    29.478] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    29.478] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    29.478] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    29.478] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    29.478] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    29.478]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    29.479]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    29.479] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    29.479] Require OpenGL version 2.1 or later.
[    29.479] (EE) modeset(0): Failed to initialize glamor at ScreenInit() time.
[    29.479] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    29.479] (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
[    29.479] (EE)
[    29.479] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    29.479] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
```

The 'startx' command on the console outputs the following (typed in manually here because I can't copy-and-paste from the text mode console; there's no mouse support there):

```
Xorg X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-140-generic 1686 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux de945 5.4.0-80-generic #90~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 13 19:38:58 UtC 201 i686
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmliuz-5.4.0-80-generic root=UUID=5e51f27a-0823-4e70-aff8-7c513bc63fb3 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Buil Date: 08 April 2021 01:52:21PM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.9 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make surethatyou have the latest version.
Marker: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting, (**) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational, (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/frankvw/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log",Time: Mon Jul 26 13:31:18 2021
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Require OpenGL version 2.1 or later.
(EE) Fatal server error: (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0. (EE) Please consult the Xorg Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help. (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/frankvw/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). CLosing logfile.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
Xinit: server error
```

The command `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` entered from Remmina (on the text mode console I get an "Error: unable to open display) produces `OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.0.8`.

**Where do I go from here?** How do I find out what has been borked by the xrdp install and where, and how to fix it?

All suggestions are welcome!

// FvW

Comment: I should add that this Lubuntu install is running on an old A/Open Digital Engine using an Intel 945GM Express Chipset.

Answer (score 0):

OK... After much Googling and experimentation, the following solved the problem:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
Xorg :0 -configure
mv /root/xorg.conf.new /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-mouse
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-kbd
```

The generation of the xorg.conf.new file resulted in errors; the generated config contained duplicate `Monitor`, `Device` and `Screen` sections. I deleted the second copy of each and at the top of the config I included the following:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
        Option       "AutoAddDevices"   "false"
EndSection
```

Reboot. And there was much rejoicing.

This is "brute force' operation, forcing manual rather than probed hardware support, but it's the only thing that yielded any result at all. I/m still not sure what xrdp broke, or where, or how, or why. But this fixed it.